# How to get remainder of increadebly large number division in python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, data-science

I have an extremely large float, that I need to get the remainder of:
`7.243939818075587375725888795E+29944`
this is stored using the Decimal module, as it overflows the float datatype in python3.

Therefore I can't use % to find it and haven't been able to figure out any other way.

This number btw is the result of this equation/code:

***note: is different, but the logic is the same; for whatever reason, this would freeze;***

```
#from decimal import *
m = 11041011081081113211911111410810033321161041051153210511532973283698344321151051091121081013210111099114121112116105111110321151011141181059910132503210297991161111143210111099114121112116101100321091011151159710310133
e = 11891753
n = 11891753

print pow(m,e)) / n) # m^e/n
```

it needs to be put in the decimal function or the float will overflow.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `pow()`:
***Return x to the power y; if z is present, return x to the power y, modulo z (computed more efficiently than pow(x, y) % z). The two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power operator: x**y.***

See: [2. Built-in Functions - pow(x, y[, z])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow)

```
import datetime

m = 11041011081081113211911111410810033321161041051153210511532973283698344321151051091121081013210111099114121112116105111110321151011141181059910132503210297991161111143210111099114121112116101100321091011151159710310133
e = 11891753
n = 11891753

start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(pow(m, e, n))
end = datetime.datetime.now()
# Result: 476638


print(f'Elapsed time: {(end - start).microseconds} [ms]')
# Elapsed time: 36902 [ms]
```

Comment: thanks this was very helpful. However if there a way if e was a float?

Comment: in `pow()` 3rd argument (`z`) is not allowed, unless all arguments are integers.